# Making my footer width background colour fill the browser window

Tags: html, css, background, footer

As my title i'm after some help making my footer width background colour fill the browser window.

My footer tag is built up inside my wrapper which is 1000px; so when coming to give my footer a background colour the body background colour shows up down the sides. i came up with the quick idea of margin-left -1000px, then padding-left 1000px and the same with the right, which looks find on a desktop but when viewing on a iphone or ipad this didnt work to well.

website test page.... http://www.rubb.co.uk/test/index.htm

Please note website content is still needing to be completed. Currently redesigning the full site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to take your footer out of the wrapper. Change your wrapper definition to use .wrapper instead #wrapper so you can use it more than once, so you could have something like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- rest of website here -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- footer content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can give your #footer a background colour

Comment: THanks for that, slightly further forward but now everything is left aligned... tried the normal methods but isnt working. If i give the wrapper a width of 1000px, if put the footer back to square 1... any ideas? cheers

Comment: Looking through your HTML is not exactly what I suggested, but you can easily solve it by adding: margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; to #top_bar, #header, #content and #footer, that will center align those DIVS

Answer (score 0):

While your particular case won't help anybody else. You need to change your markup from:

```
#wrapper
   -> #footer_box
```

To

```
#wrapper
#footer_box
```

Now footer_box will have width 100%. You're `#wrapper` has a fixed width so it will not come out of its flow with `position: fixed` and then it will  always be visible.